# How to treat HttpURLConnection when failed to connect to URL

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin, httpurlconnection

When my database is running, everything is okey. But when is not running my mobile app always crash.

Error message:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /httpURL.

How to fix problem?

here is my code:

```
AsyncTaskHandleJson().execute(url)    

inner class AsyncTaskHandleJson : AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String {
            var text: String
            var connection = URL(url[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            try {
                connection.connect()
                text = connection.inputStream.use { it.reader().use { reader -> reader.readText() } }
            } finally {
                connection.disconnect()
            }
            return text
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            handleJson(result)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you not `catch` the error?

Comment: Like creativecreatorormaybenot stated just catch the error (if there is one) then before you `handleJson(result)` check to see if `result` has usable data. If not bypass `handleJson()` and present a toast to the user that the db is not reachable (or what ever you want to tell them)

Comment: @Barns how to check if result has usable data?

Comment: It looks like you already have an accepted answer?  what do you not understand?

Comment: @Barns when method handleJson is called, app will crash and here is error message: pastebin.com/RNLmtSV6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no `catch` block in your code, you are not catching any exceptions currently.

If you would like to handle the `ConnectException`, then you simply have to catch it:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg url: String?): String {
    var text = ""
    var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null

    try {
        connection = URL(url[0]).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.connect()
        text = connection.inputStream.use {
            it.reader().use { reader ->
                reader.readText()
            }
        }
    } catch (ce: ConnectException) {
        // ConnectionException occurred, do whatever you'd like
        ce.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // some other Exception occurred
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        connection?.disconnect()
    }

    return text
}
```

Check out the [Exceptions reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html).

Comment: Thanks, but when it called handleJson, app again crash, here is error message: https://pastebin.com/RNLmtSV6

Comment: @misolo89 Of course, if an `Exception` occurs, then you're passing an empty `String` to `handleJson()`. You should either make `handleJson ()` to handle an empty `String` accordingly, or don't even call `handleJson()` when you have no content to handle.